# How distribution of Cordapp jars happens in a Business Network in corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

On joining a business network the node want to get the cordapp installed.How is the procedure?Is there any existing flow for this purpose or can we create a custom flow for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the network is managed. Also in the Corda Network documentation [here](https://corda.network/participation/index) (step 7) they do not mention a standard way to do it, it is based on the agreement among parties:

> Installation and configuration of your Corda applications must be undertaken by the node operator. [...] Specifics on application usage or installation should be available from your CorDapp provider.

Technically, you can find an interesting reference implementation of a CorDapp Distribution Service [here](https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/blob/master/bn-apps/cordapp-updates-distribution/design/design.md) to manage the distribution and management of the updates:

> targets scenarios when Business Network members maintain their nodes
> by themselves and can decide on what version of a CorDapp they would
> like to upgrade to. This design does not target scenarios where
> upgrade function is centralised and the whole network can be shut down
> to perform stop-upgrade-restart.